# Android - Code design of notification feature

Tags: java, android, notifications, push-notification, toast

I am working on an Android social app. It contains notification feature such as `when A send a friend request to B, B should later get a notification icon shows 1 friend request on App bar` (not a toast).

In order to know if the user has a friend request or not, the app will need to periodically send HTTP request to my backend API query for any notification. This should be performed in background. 
I am not sure what is a good way of implement such a feature. Should I use a Android Service? or should I spin a thread by myself? How to design and implement this to make sure it won't drain the data and battery? If I want to add a toast feature later, how should I design the whole client side notification system to make sure its easy to add the toast functionality?

Code pointers or suggestions will be greatly helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Periodically sending web-requests to check whether the user has any notifications or not is very expensive task for battery life.

Rather I suggest to use Push Notifications. There are third-party libraries available for this. Also recently Google Cloud has started Google Cloud Messaging for Android which is powerful framework to sync data between devices for specific app on certain events.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Please follow the link above for more information to use Google Cloud Messaging for Android.

Also please have a look at following framework. It may of your interest.

https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

sending web-requests periodically is even more expensive task (for battery) when the internet is not available in the device.